# BlackMagic UlraStudio Mini Recorder - Black Screen on all Inputs - HDMI input to Mac Pro

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, input-source

I am trying to get a live feed via the following setup on my MacBook Pro 2012 running Sierra 10.13.2.

HDMI Out on camera, plugged into HDMI In on BlackMagic device >> Thunderbolt out plugged into MacBook Thunderbolt port.

I have a few Camera's I have tested but none work.

I have tried BlackMagic drivers 10.9.7 and 10.9.5. When I open the BlackMagic Media Express, I just get a blank/black screen on the "Log/Capture" screen.

In the BlackMagic driver settings I have selected HDMI and under "Conversions" I have set "None".

The end goal is to use IStopMotion, which shows the device "Black Magic" as an option, but it is also a black screen.

The cameras I have tried are Sony HDR-SR10, Sony HDR-CX130 and Lumix DMC-GF1.

Comment: It's not quite off topic, but I don't think you'll find a lot of support for this here. That said, having used a Blackmagic Intensity Shuttle over USB on Windows, it simply refused to work with the HDMI out on our camera (I think it was some Sony Handycam?). Our resolution ended up being to use an Elgato HD60 with the camera and the Blackmagic Intensity Shuttle with a different video source that we also needed to capture, which worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

We had to go buy a new mini HDMI to HDMI adapter. After the software worked as expected. Good Job BlackMagic on a nice piece of SW.